# Bing Maps Geodata Decompress Algorithm port to PHP

Tags: java, php, bing-maps, compression, bing-api

I am trying to port Microsoft's Decompress Algorithm to PHP from Java(or maybe its C++ or C# since that's Microsoft). This is an algorithm that takes their compressed shape data from their Bing Maps Geodata API results and expands it into lat/lon coordinates. They have posted their algorithm on their site over at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306801.aspx

I have a list of coordinates stored in my database and I am trying to retrieve the array of coordinates that define a polygon to work with the shape. My results differ. Can anyone point out discrepancies between the two?

**EDIT**: I believe my problem lies in the fact that PHP does not handle LONG type integers and precision loss occurs when doing bitwise operations. I might need to convert some operations to use BCMath. Help here?

**Decompression Algorithm (Microsoft's)**

```
public const string safeCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-";

private static bool TryParseEncodedValue(string value, out List<Coordinate> parsedValue)
{
    parsedValue = null;
    var list = new List<Coordinate>();
    int index = 0;
    int xsum = 0, ysum = 0;

    while (index < value.Length)        // While we have more data,
    {
        long n = 0;                     // initialize the accumulator
        int k = 0;                      // initialize the count of bits

        while (true)
        {
            if (index >= value.Length)  // If we ran out of data mid-number
                return false;           // indicate failure.

            int b = safeCharacters.IndexOf(value[index++]);

            if (b == -1)                // If the character wasn't on the valid list,
                return false;           // indicate failure.

            n |= ((long)b & 31) << k;   // mask off the top bit and append the rest to the accumulator
            k += 5;                     // move to the next position
            if (b < 32) break;          // If the top bit was not set, we're done with this number.
        }

       // The resulting number encodes an x, y pair in the following way:
       //
       //  ^ Y
       //  |
       //  14
       //  9 13
       //  5 8 12
       //  2 4 7 11
       //  0 1 3 6 10 ---> X

       // determine which diagonal it's on
       int diagonal = (int)((Math.Sqrt(8 * n + 5) - 1) / 2);

       // subtract the total number of points from lower diagonals
       n -= diagonal * (diagonal + 1L) / 2;

       // get the X and Y from what's left over
       int ny = (int)n;
       int nx = diagonal - ny;

       // undo the sign encoding
       nx = (nx >> 1) ^ -(nx & 1);
        ny = (ny >> 1) ^ -(ny & 1);

        // undo the delta encoding
        xsum += nx;
        ysum += ny;

        // position the decimal point
        list.Add(new Coordinate { Latitude = ysum * 0.00001, Longitude = xsum * 0.00001 });
    }

    parsedValue = list;
    return true;
}
```

**My Decompression Algorithm (PHP)**

```
function tryParseEncodedValue($value) {   
    $value = 'vx1vilihnM6hR7mEl2Q';
    var_error_log($value);
    $safeCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-";
    $list = array();
    $index = 0;
    (int)$xsum = 0;
    (int)$ysum = 0;

    while ($index < strlen($value))   // While we have more data,
    {
        $n = 0;                       // initialize the accumulator
        $k = 0;                       // initialize the count of bits

        while (true)
        {
            if ($index >= strlen($value)) // If we ran out of data mid-number
            {
                var_error_log('failed: inxed >= strlen($value)');
                return false;             // indicate failure.
            }
            (int)$b = strpos($safeCharacters, $value[$index++]);

            if (!$b) {                    // If the character wasn't on the valid list,
                var_error_log('failed: character not in valid list');
                return false;             // indicate failure.
            }
            $n |= ($b & 31) << $k;        // mask off the top bit and append the rest to the accumulator
            $k = $k+5;                    // move to the next position
            if ($b < 32) break;           // If the top bit was not set, we're done with this number.
        }

        // The resulting number encodes an x, y pair in the following way:
        //
        //  ^ Y
        //  |
        //  14
        //  9 13
        //  5 8 12
        //  2 4 7 11
        //  0 1 3 6 10 ---> X

        // determine which diagonal it's on
        $diagonal = (int)((sqrt(8 * $n + 5) - 1) / 2);

        // subtract the total number of points from lower diagonals
        $n -= $diagonal * ($diagonal + (int)1) / 2;

        // get the X and Y from what's left over
        $ny = (int)$n;
        $nx = $diagonal - $ny;

        // undo the sign encoding
        $nx = pow(($nx >> 1), (-($nx & 1)) );
        $ny = pow(($ny >> 1), (-($ny & 1)) );

        // undo the delta encoding
        $xsum += $nx;
        $ysum += $ny;

        // position the decimal point
        $coordinates = array($ysum * 0.00001, $xsum * 0.00001);
        array_push($list, $coordinates); 
    }

    $parsedValue = $list;
    var_error_log($parsedValue);
    return $parsedValue;
}
```

**Known Input** 
Microsoft gives an example input and output to validate your algorithms with. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj158958.aspx#TestingYourAlg

```
compressed shape = 'vx1vilihnM6hR7mEl2Q'
```

**Expected Output**

```
an array of coordinates
35.894309002906084, -110.72522000409663
35.893930979073048, -110.72577999904752
35.893744984641671, -110.72606003843248
35.893366960808635, -110.72661500424147
```

**My Output**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1.0E-5)
    [1]=>
    float(1.0E-5)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1.027027027027E-5)
    [1]=>
    float(1.0181818181818E-5)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1.0825825825826E-5)
    [1]=>
    float(1.0552188552189E-5)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1.1103603603604E-5)
    [1]=>
    float(1.0734006734007E-5)
  }
}
```

So, we can see that the PHP output is not being calculated correctly and I have a feeling it has to do with the differences with casting to Long integers in Java and running bitwise operations on integers. PHP is supposed to handle integers whether they are long or floats or ints, but I have a feeling I am overlooking something.

I bet the problem has to do with this line. Can anyone point out discrepancies?

```
n |= ((long)b & 31) << k;   // mask off the top bit and append the rest to the accumulator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted the C# code to PHP. The problem did lie in the fact that precision was lost with large floating numbers in php. Since some of the values were going above the bounds of 32bit integers and were being stored as 64bit ints in C#, these values had to be converted to [PHP's GMP class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php). GMP supports long bitwise operations.

```
/*
*   Microsoft's decompression algorithm - php version
*   returns an array of coordinates (pairs of doubles)
*/
function tryParseEncodedValue($value) {

    $safeCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-";
    $list = array();
    (int)$index = 0;
    (int)$xsum = 0;
    (int)$ysum = 0;

    while ($index < strlen($value))        // While we have more data,
    {
        $n = 0;                             // initialize the accumulator
        $k = 0;                              // initialize the count of bits

        while (true)
        {
            if ($index >= strlen($value)) // If we ran out of data mid-number
            {
                var_error_log('failed: inxed >= strlen($value)');
                return false;             // indicate failure.
            }
            $b = strpos($safeCharacters, $value[$index++]);

            if ($b === false) {           // If the character wasn't on the valid list,
                var_error_log('failed: character not in valid list');
                return false;             // indicate failure.
            }

            // mask off the top bit and append the rest to the accumulator
            // n |= ((long)b & 31) << k;
            $bgmp = gmp_init($b);                           // Here i'm breaking out this function
            $bitwiseand = gmp_and($bgmp, 31);               // on multiple lines because there's 
            $shifted = gmp_shiftl($bitwiseand, $k);         // so many steps
            $n = gmp_or($n, $shifted);
            $k += 5;
            if (gmp_cmp($bgmp, gmp_init(32)) < 0) break;    // gmp compare: b < 32
        }

        // The resulting number encodes an x, y pair in the following way:
        //
        //  ^ Y
        //  |
        //  14
        //  9 13
        //  5 8 12
        //  2 4 7 11
        //  0 1 3 6 10 ---> X

        // determine which diagonal it's on
        //$diagonal = (int)((sqrt(8 * $n + 5) - 1) / 2);
        $diagonal = gmp_intval(gmp_div_q(gmp_sub(gmp_sqrt(gmp_add(gmp_mul($n, 8), 5)), 1), 2));

        // subtract the total number of points from lower diagonals
        // n -= diagonal * (diagonal + 1L) / 2;
        $n = gmp_sub($n, gmp_div_q(gmp_mul($diagonal, gmp_add($diagonal, 1)), 2));

        // get the X and Y from what's left over
        (int)$ny = gmp_intval($n);
        (int)$nx = $diagonal - $ny;

        // undo the sign encoding
        $nx = ($nx >> 1)^ (-($nx & 1));
        $ny = ($ny >> 1)^ (-($ny & 1));

        // undo the delta encoding
        $xsum += $nx;
        $ysum += $ny;

        // position the decimal point
        $coordinate = array($ysum * 0.00001, $xsum * 0.00001);
        array_push($list, $coordinate);
    }

    return $list;
}

// shift left, $x number to shift, $n shift n times. 
function gmp_shiftl($x,$n) { 
    return(gmp_mul($x,gmp_pow(2,$n)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your issue is when you converted the following C# code:

```
nx = (nx >> 1) ^ -(nx & 1);
ny = (ny >> 1) ^ -(ny & 1);
```

In your PHP code you convert this to:

```
$nx = pow(($nx >> 1), (-($nx & 1)) );
$ny = pow(($ny >> 1), (-($ny & 1)) );
```

In C# ^ is a bitwise XOR operation and not a power. PHP uses the same symbol for a bitwise XOR, so try changing you code to this:

```
$nx = ($nx >> 1) ^ (-($nx & 1));
$ny = ($ny >> 1) ^ (-($ny & 1));
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you soo much for finding that error! I really can't believe that someone so involved with Bing Maps as you responded and actually found one of my errors.

Comment: I made the change you suggested but still am getting incorrect output - listed here: (-4516.79232, -6220.62592)(-4516.7927, -6220.62648)(-4516.79289, -6220.62676)(-4516.79326, -6220.62732)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! In the code, once we executed down to $ny and $nx, those values were back in the range of 32bit integers and I didn't have to use GMP on those lines.